# Find and return the height of subtree rooted at that node in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Tree a = Tip | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I need to return a tree with the same shape as its argument, but with each node label replaced with a pair containing the original label in the second field. The first field should be the height of the subtree rooted at that node.
Here is what I wrote:

```
heights :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)

heights Tip = Tip
heights (Bin Tip x Tip) = Bin Tip (1,x) Tip
heights (Bin l x r) = heights (Bin (heights l) (1 + max(heights l)(heights r)) (heights r))
```

I got errors for my code:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `(Integer, a)'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for heights :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)
          at Project2.hs:47:12
    Expected type: Tree a
      Actual type: Tree (Integer, a)
    In the return type of a call of `heights'
    In the first argument of `Bin', namely `(heights l)'
    In the first argument of `heights', namely
      `(Bin (heights l) ((1 + max (heights l) (heights r))) (heights r))'
```

Comment: i feel so lost for this problem...

Comment: Aha, that's a reasonable attempt. How about you also add the error message?

Comment: i added those errors.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to *extract* the height information from the recursive calls. That's in principle a good approach, but the problem is that `heights` gives back a whole tree, not just the height of a given tree. However, you can easily extract **the** height from that:

```
extractPrecomputedHeight :: Tree (Integer, a) -> Integer
extractPrecomputedHeight Tip = 1
extractPrecomputedHeight (Bin _ (h,_) _) = h
```

Then, just use that to measure the subtrees. Preferrably only go down into these *once* each, with a `where` binding:

```
heights (Bin l x r) = Bin _ _ _
 where [l', r'] = heights <$> [l,r]
       h = 1 + max (extractPrecomputedHeight l') (extractPrecomputedHeight r')
```

Fill in the `_` gaps yourself. (GHC can help you with that: it will show for each `_`, what type it expects there, and what type the available local bindings have, so it's easy to find the right definition.)

Comment: i got error that parse error on input '=' for your code......

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that doesn't make sense, typed holes aren't parse errors.

Comment: @Kris there's no parse error in my code. Make sure you've actually got the indentation and all right.